# Using the GAE remote_api to Create Local Scripts

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to do some local processing of data entries from the GAE datastore and I am trying to do this by using the remote_api. I just want to write some quick processing scripts that pull some data, but I am getting import errors saying that Python cannot import from google.

Am I supposed to run the script from within the development environment somehow. Or perhaps I need to include all of the google stuff in my Python path? That seems excessive though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is including the paths that onerous ?

Normally the remote_api shell is used interactively but it is a good tool that you can use as the basis of acheiving what your want.

The simplest way will be to copy and modify the remote_api shell  so that rather than presenting an interactive shell you get it to run a named script.

That way it will deal with all the path setup.

In the past I have integrated the remote_api inside a zope server, so that plone could publish stuff to appengine.  All sort of things are possible with remote_api, however you need to deal with imports like anything else in python, except that appengine libraries are not installed in site-packages.

Comment: I don't like this solution because the include path is somewhat convoluted and I don't want to rely on internal Google configs for library files. In the event they ever moved then it would break the scripts.

Comment: Also, copying and modifying the remote_api shell seems like a lot, I checked out the file and there's a lot in there. Is there a way to run the GAE python interpreter instead of the standard one installed on your machine? That seems like the path of least resistance.

Comment: To modify remote_api_shell to run an arbitrary script is about 3-4 lines of code.  ANd yes, if you just run remote_api_shell you have exactly that, an sheel with access to remote api, its a really good way of debugging and manipulating data.

Comment: What about remote_api_stub? Presumably they intended that file for this sort of use case, not a repurposing of remote_api_shell? I'm somewhat unclear on how exactly I'm supposed to use the stub. They give an example, but you would get a bunch of import errors without including all of the Google libraries

Comment: Correct, thats what I use inside zope, however you said you didn't want to set up the paths for importing libraries, thats why I suggested using the remote_api_shell and modifying it to run an arbitrary script.  Just trying to come up with an answer that you find acceptable, - either deal with importing google libs and setting the paths etc... or copy and modify remote_api_shell, take you pick which you find the least offensive.

Comment: fair enough, thanks for helping to sort this out. I wonder though why Google doesn't make this a bit more straightforward? Interacting with your data objects outside of the webframework seems like a reasonable thing to want to do